# How to setup Kubernetes (v1.9.5) Audit based on coreos (1688.5.3)

Tags: audit, coreos

Team,

- Any special requirements to setup kubernetes(v1.9.5) audit following the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) based on CoreOS 1688.5.3? (kubespray “v2.5.0” )
- I can see nothing generated here /var/log/kube-audit, which should be, any tips? Thanks!

```

```
$ sudo vi /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Policy
rules:
- level: Metadata


$ sudo vi kube-apiserver
...
--audit-policy-file=/etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml 
--audit-log-path=/var/log/kube-audit 
--audit-log-format=json
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's in the pod kube-apiserver:/var/log/kube-audit